# I want create a url rewriting that get last folder and use it as file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, urlrewriter

The first folder (lang) is fixed and the "output" should be have only last folder with ".php" extension.

(Is possible to get first folder without create n rule for each language? "/en/blog/")

(Is possible add the slash at the end of the url if not present ? "/en/blog" --> "/en/blog/" )

## Examples:

**From:**

```
/it/blog/
```

**To:**

```
/it/blog.php
```

---

**From:**

```
/it/blog/notizie/
```

**To:**

```
/it/notizie.php
```

---

**From:**

```
/it/blog/notizie/file/
```

**To:**

```
/it/file.php
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
DirectorySlash On
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## Add a trailing slash if missing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)[^/][?/]?\s
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]{2})/.*?([^/.]+)/$ $1/$2.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: The system works perfectly with `/it/blog/`, with `/it/blog.php`, with `/it/blog.php?aa=dummy` but there is a strange anomaly. If you call a non-existent file as `/it/blog123.php?aa=dummy` system call `/it/blog123.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php etc etc`. That is, if there are parameters in the url.

Comment: **So it's okay for me.** I report you another anomaly but that you do not need to do :-) . If I use `/it/blog.php` is all ok.
If I use `/it/blog.php/` (_with slash at the end_) or use `/it/blog123.php` (_file does not exist_) the server put `The requested URL /it/php.php was not found on this server`. If I use `/it/blog123.php?aa=dummy` (_file does not exist + parameters_) the server put `The requested URL /it/php.php/ was not found on this server` and the url change to `/it/php.php/?aa=dummy`

Comment: Now also changes always the url in the browser (if `/it/blog.php/` or `/it/blog123.php` url change to `/it/php.php/`; if `/it/blog123.php?aa=dummy` url change to `/it/php.php/?aa=dummy`); **but do not worry, that's fine the previous version ;-)**